# WPF/MVVM with Entity Framework, Repository and Unit of Work pattern

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, wpf, repository

I'm building WPF/MVVM application and I'm struggling implementing Unit of work pattern.

The part, about which I'm not sure is `UnitOfWork` class. Here is my thought:

It's coupled with my repositories and `MyDatabaseContext`. At first impression, it doesn't sound good. But, I think, `UnitOfWork` should be coupled with `DbContext`. Technically it should be named `MyDatabaseUnitOfWork`. What do you think?

**Unit of work:**

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable 
{
    int Complete();
    ICustomerRepository Customers { get; }
    IPhoneRepository Phones { get; }
    IAddressRepository Address { get; }
}

public class UnitOfWork<TContext> : IUnitOfWork
    where TContext : MyDatabaseContext, new()
{
    public ICustomerRepository Customers { get; }
    public IPhoneRepository Phones { get; }
    public IAddressRepository Address { get; }

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        context = new TContext();
        Customers = new CustomerRepository(context);
        Phones = new PhoneRepository(context);
        Address = new AddressRepository(context);
    } 

    public int Complete()
    {
        return context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }
}

public interface IUnitOfWorkFactory
{
    IUnitOfWork Create();
}

public class UnitOfWorkFactory : IUnitOfWorkFactory
{
    public IUnitOfWork Create()
    {
        return new UnitOfWork<MyDatabaseContext>();
    }
}
```

**Useage:**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        try
        {
            UnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
            unityContainer.RegisterType<IUnitOfWorkFactory, UnitOfWorkFactory>();
            unityContainer.RegisterType<MainWindowViewModel>();

            var window = new MainWindow()
            {
                DataContext = unityContainer.Resolve<MainWindowViewModel>()
            };
            window.Show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}


public class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWorkFactory unitOfWorkFactory;

    public MainWindowViewModel(IUnitOfWorkFactory uowFactory)
    {
        unitOfWorkFactory = uowFactory;
    }

    private int DoSomething()
    {
        using (var unitOfWork = unitOfWorkFactory.Create())
        {


        }
    }
}
```

**Sample repository:**

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    TEntity Get(int id);
    IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate);
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();

    void Add(TEntity entity);
    void AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);

    void Remove(TEntity entity);
    void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);
}

public interface ICustomerRepository : IRepository<Customer>
{
    IEnumerable<Customer> GetTopCustomers(int count);
}

internal class CustomerRepository : Repository<Customer>, ICustomerRepository
{
    private MyDatabaseContext MyDatabaseContext => Context as MyDatabaseContext;

    internal CustomerRepository(MyDatabaseContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetTopCustomers(int count)
    {
        return MyDatabaseContext.Customers.ToList();
    }
}
```

---

**Here is my second option:** Is it necessary?

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable 
{
    int Complete();
}


public interface IMyDatabaseUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork 
{
    int Complete();
    ICustomerRepository Customers { get; }
    IPhoneRepository Phones { get; }
    IAddressRepository Address { get; }
}

public class MyDatabaseUnitOfWork<TContext> : IMyDatabaseUnitOfWork
    where TContext : MyDatabaseContext, new()
{
    public ICustomerRepository Customers { get; }
    public IPhoneRepository Phones { get; }
    public IAddressRepository Address { get; }

    public MyDatabaseUnitOfWork()
    {
        context = new TContext();
        Customers = new CustomerRepository(context);
        Phones = new PhoneRepository(context);
        Address = new AddressRepository(context);
    } 

    public int Complete()
    {
        return context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: EF already implements the pattern Unit of Work. Does your class solve a real problem for you or is it just xomplicating things?

Comment: @MattiasÅslund Well, in my "second option", my UnitOfWork is completely decoupled from EF or any other ORM/Service or whatever, isn't it? So my viewmodel or business layer doesn't know about EF or any other ORM.

Comment: @Marshall Mattia's point is: do you **need** it in **this moment** or in a reasonable near future? If not then you're writing tons of unnecessary code...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti  *If not then you're writing tons of unnecessary code... * It's not tons, 8 lines of getters and 6 lines of other code. Nothing to get worked up over.

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca **much more** than that. Whole repository pattern is useless more often than not with EF (unless you're planning to use different ORMs). All presented code is unnecessary (and it's still far away to be complete), not even mention that it's working all in-memory (Func<> instead of Expression<> and ToList()) then probably it's a fictional example. Now, given the amount of required code to write (few thousands line - when **half properly done** and still missing some EF features - compared to zero) with the advantage of...hmmm well which advantage?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I can't use the chat, so I'm replying here. About `Func` and `ToList`, missing essential features you think he will need: you should put those in an answer. *All presented code is unnecessary* The rest of the application uses the interfaces and `OnStartUp` uses the implementations, I don't think the program would even compile if you removed anything.

Comment: Of course calling code should be updated if this intermediate layer is removed...you can read it as _"all presented code - with the exception of calling code - is unnecessary"_. I'm not thinking about missing essential features he WILL need. I'm exactly _against_ this because it's a feature he does not need now!!! Fictional examples are 50 lines of code, final implementation is...how much? thousands lines? What's the **immediate** (or near future) benefit? Please note that I'm not an XP _adept_ but unnecessary layers and complexity always make me ask "why" (he may have reasons)

Comment: thanks for contribution! @AdrianoRepetti can you post the code in an answer with your idea? I'm not sure I understood you correctly. Reading the code is so much easier. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Marshall well, actually my idea is to **avoid** that code until the moment you will know for sure that you will need it (if ever...). Practically an empty answer! ;) IMO unless you need it now (will you switch to another not-POCO ORM soon? do you use two or more ORMs?) then I'd simply avoid any extra complexity.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti So, wait a second... I need to make sure I understood you correctly. Are you suggesting.. **A)** injecting `MyDatabaseContext` into every ViewModel? (DbContext is EF's unitOfWork, right?). Or  **B)** injecting `UnityContainer` and then in ViewModel resolving `MyDatabaseContext`. Although, the **B** is a service locator antipattern, so I'm not sure. Are you suggesting **A** option?

Comment: If you don't have any other special requirement then IMO option A because you won't use additional complexity you may introduce. Also testing is easy with EF because there are mocking tools (yes it implements UoW). However often I found I need a factory then I'd inject that instead of directly context (little indirection). Please note that to have Repository is not so common but possible (it depends...) but that change is possible in any moment in future. Unit of work, however, is useless with EF.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using loosely coupled code. IoC / DI are a great way to go. Example:

```
public class ImmutableUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly ICustomerRepository _customers;
    private readonly IPhoneRepository _phones;
    private readonly IAddressRepository _address;

    public ImmutableUnitOfWork(
        ICustomerRepository customers,
        IPhoneRepository phones,
        IAddressRepository address)
    {
        _customers = customers;
        _phones = phones;
        _address = address;
    } 
}
```

using StructureMap your dependency resolution should look something in the lines of:

```
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.Scan(scan =>
            {
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                scan.AssemblyContainingType<ICustomerRepository>();  // Core
                scan.AssemblyContainingType<CustomerRepository>();   // Infrastructure
                scan.AssemblyContainingType<MyDatabaseContext>();    // Just in case 
            });
            x.For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(Repository<>));

            // WithDefaultConventions basically says if you name interfaces with
            // same name, but with "I" prefix you do not need following:
            x.For(typeof(IMyDatabaseContext)).Use(typeof(MyDatabaseContext));
            x.For(typeof(ICustomerRepository)).Use(typeof(CustomerRepository));
        });
```

but I understand if it is for learning purposes.

---

From code perspective :

ICustomerRepository is a service, not a repository. `IRepository<TEntity>` - is leaky, especially `IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate);`. If you feel that you really need it, try using specification pattern instead. This is just bad on many levels:

```
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: Your code BL code would go inside ImmutableUnitOfWork class.